# How to deal with a single instance event in a mixed integer linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

Let's say that a you have x=(1,2,...,10) machines at t=0(beginning of operation). You are planning to buy a certain number of machines and/or to salvage some of your preexisting machines. Given t=(0,1,2,...,100) as the operation time. Cost components include daily fixed and variable costs of running a machine, cost of salvaging a preexisting machine, and cost of buying a machine and you need to minimize the costs involved.

```
Let A = if a preexisting machine should run in a given day (binary)
B = if a preexisting machine is available (binary)
C = if a new machine should run in a given day (binary)
D = if a new machine is available (binary)
If a machine is available then it can be used (A <= B) and (C <= D)
```

How do you add to a model single instance costs like if a preexisting machine is salvaged and if a new machine is bought?

Comment: If you only want to minimize cost, the best thing to do is to do nothing (with a cost of zero). You are missing some demand in this model. Not sure if you need to model individual machines or not from this description.  The description is not precise and detailed enough for that.

Comment: Are all of A, B, C, D givens, or are you optimising for all of them? How exactly do you calculate "fixed and variable costs" - is the fixed cost paid regardless of whether the machine runs or not, and the variable cost is paid if the machine runs on a given day? Why are B and D binary - wouldn't this be an integer, the "number of available machines"?